# Pandas Nested Array Columns

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas Nested Array Columns: Details of my question listed below:

I have a column that is a nested array in pandas, and is as below when you print

How can I get the length of the nested **parameters** array to be a new column value ?

```
print(df["arraycolumn"])
```

**Prints:**

```
[
        {
           "type":"auth",
           "name":"activity",
           "parameters":[
              {
                 "name":"api_name",
                 "value":"admin"
              },
              {
                 "name":"method_name",
                 "value":"directory.users.list"
              },
              {
                 "name":"client_id",
                 "value":"722230783769-dsta4bi9fkom72qcu0t34aj3qpcoqloq.apps.googleusercontent.com"
              },
              {
                 "name":"num_response_bytes",
                 "intValue":"7158"
              },
              {
                 "name":"product_bucket",
                 "value":"GSUITE_ADMIN"
              },
              {
                 "name":"app_name",
                 "value":"Untitled project"
              },
              {
                 "name":"client_type",
                 "value":"WEB"
              }
           ]
        }
     ]   },   {
     "kind":"admin#reports#activity",
     "id":{
        "time":"2022-05-05T23:58:48.914Z",
        "uniqueQualifier":"-4002873813067783265",
        "applicationName":"token",
        "customerId":"C02f6wppb"
     },
     "etag":"\"5T53xK7dpLei95RNoKZd9uz5Xb8LJpBJb72fi2HaNYM/9DTdB8t7uixvUbjo4LUEg53_gf0\"",
     "actor":{
        "email":"nancy.admin@hyenacapital.net",
        "profileId":"100230688039070881323"
     },
     "ipAddress":"54.80.168.30",
     "events":[
        {
           "type":"auth",
           "name":"activity",
           "parameters":[
              {
                 "name":"api_name",
                 "value":"gmail"
              },
              {
                 "name":"method_name",
                 "value":"gmail.users.messages.list"
              },
              {
                 "name":"client_id",
                 "value":"927538837578.apps.googleusercontent.com"
              },
              {
                 "name":"num_response_bytes",
                 "intValue":"2"
              },
              {
                 "name":"product_bucket",
                 "value":"GMAIL"
              },
              {
                 "name":"app_name",
                 "value":"Zapier"
              },
              {
                 "name":"client_type",
                 "value":"WEB"
              }
           ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.apply` to apply an arbitrary Python function to each element of a `Series`:

```py
def get_parameters(obj):
    return obj[0]["parameters"]

df["arraycolumn_parameters_length"] = (
    df["arraycolumn"]
    .apply(lambda y: len(get_parameters(y)))
)
```

Of course, you might have to add error checking or other additional logic to the `get_parameters` function above, as needed.

Answer (score -1):

How about using `.str`?

```
df['arraycolumn'].str['parameters'].str.len()
```

Comment: I tried that but you  "Can only use .str accessor with string values"

Comment: Will you please send the result of `print(type(df['arraycolumn'].iloc[0]))` ?

Comment: <class 'dict'>
[{'type': 'auth', 'name': 'activity', 'parameters': [{'name': 'api_name', 'value': 'gmail'}, {'name': 'method_name', 'value': 'gmail.users.settings.getAutoForwarding'}, {'name': 'client_id', 'value': '113024082505006618692'}, {'name': 'num_response_bytes', 'intValue': '2'}, {'name': 'product_bucket', 'value': 'GMAIL'}, {'name': 'app_name', 'value': 'Test'}, {'name': 'client_type', 'value': 'WEB'}]}]

Comment: this did the trick 

["arraycolumn"].iloc[0][0].get('parameters') -- but I need to get the length now

Comment: this did the trick

print(len(df["arraycolumn"].iloc[0][0].get('parameters')))

Comment: but how do I get each record to have its respective length correct?